# Solr and JSON types

Tags: json, solr

I am using DataImportHandler from Database. The database has a column `"JsonLog"` of type string, which contains a JSON object. I want to import it to solr, but solr does not have a native JSON type.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to import the JsonLog to be part of the schema? Meaning, if JsonLog contains something like `"{'size' = 5}"`, can I have solr recognize `size` as a field?
2. Is there a way to import JSON strings as JSON objects in solr? `string` and `text_general` do not seem to work: they are not searchable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about string and text_general not being searchable? Which database engine are you using?

Comment: @MatsLindh I mean that If I put a json object inside a string or text_general I can't search inside the json object.

Comment: How are you searching - what does your query look like? What does the analysis page show for content + query? The tokenizer for the standard text_general field may leave some characters behind in tokens that you don't expect.